# using AJAX to check for database updates and notify

Tags: ajax, database, notifications

I need an **ajax** script to ckeck if there is an *entry* of data in the database and show *notification* on the page for each entry .I want the notification to be shown to every user viewing that page .

I tried the following but it is not giving needed output:

**main.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='ajx.js'></script>
</head>
</html>
```

**pop.php**

```
<?php
try{
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;  
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT `user`.`name`,`user`.`page` FROM `people`.`user` ORDER BY `user`.`index` DESC",$con);

    if(!$q)
    {
    throw new Exception('Uncaught Exception occurred');
     }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
Echo "";
}

$results = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);


echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

**ajx.js**

```
$.ajax({
url: "pop.php",
dataType: "json",
success: function(json){
    var dataArray = JSON.decode(json);
    dataArray.each(function(entry){
        alert(entry.name);
    }
}
});
```

***I am not getting result when i load main.html*** .I think some statement is needed to print the result.

Answer (score 1):

which specific aspect of that script would you like clarification on writing? do you have a specific question in regards to where you might be having problems?

**You could use something like this:**

PHP File: (get_notifications.php)

```
$q = /*your query to database*/
$query = mysql_query($q, $dbConnect);
$results = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo json_encode($results);
```

Javascript File:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "get_notifications.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json){
        var dataArray = JSON.decode(json);
        dataArray.each(function(entry){
            alert(entry.valueName);
        }
    }
});
```

In the javascript file "valueName" refers to the data key that you would like to output. For example if you "SELECT name FROM people", and you want to output their name it would be entry.name. You can also replace the alert with an append or something to put the data in a div or on the page.

Let me know if you need any further clarification on any of these parts. This should be able to give you a pretty good start. Hope it helps.

**Clarification:**
The file your page loads should only contain your layout and HTML as well as the script tag to include your js.

Then your php for the ajax call should be in a separate file that is called by the Ajax, not included on the page that is being loaded. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for showing interest in answering my question Greg. i dont know ajax except for how it works .I need full script .Please help me.

Comment: Greg i have shown the script that i tried , it isn't working. May be i have made any mistake.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, just corrected it in my code. It should be JSON.decode(json); not jsonstr. Since that is what is being passed back from the Ajax. Also I added another bit to my response to clarify file structure a bit; let me know if that helps.

Comment: Please if you can ,just try your code before you are posting .You are posting great scripts just you need to try it yourself till it gives correct output.If you can just try my above script ,edit it and then post it.

Comment: I revised my answer with some more code I tested that is specific to what you were working with. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I looked over your code and made a few modifications. This is the exact code I used that worked on my system with a test database that I used: (you will need to tweak it to your system environment)

**main.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ajx.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    Your body content in here...
</body>
</html>
```

**pop.php:**

```
<?php
include __DIR__.'/include/Configurations.php';
include __DIR__.'/include/DatabaseConnect.php';

global $databaseConnection;

try{
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT name, page FROM users", $databaseConnection);

    if(!$q)
    {
    throw new Exception('Uncaught Exception occurred');
    }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
Echo "";
}

$results = Array();
$i = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    $results[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

**ajx.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "pop.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json){
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<json.length; i++)
            {
                alert(json[i].name);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

When you integrate it into your actual project you can just replace the alert() function with whatever logic and output methods you want in order to get the content properly on the page. Let me know how this goes for you or if there is anything else I can help with.